# Saving changes to a jQuery sortable table

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table where the users are allowed to drag and drop rows in the order they want, and then save them. I have no problem with getting the drag and drop part to work. It's the saving I'm having issues with. I'm sending an Ajax call to a web service which will then make the save. I can't seem to actually catch the request in the web service though.

My JavaScript function looks like so:

```
$(document).ready(
            function () {
                $(".sortable").sortable({
                    update: function () {
                        serial = $('.sortable').sortable('serialize');
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "MyWebService.asmx/SortTable",
                            type: "post",
                            data: serial,
                            error: function () {
                                alert("theres an error with AJAX");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

            });
```

The JSON string looks fine from what [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) is showing me. The web service function is like so:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SortTable(String[] rows)
{
    //SaveChanges();
    return "Called!";
}
```

When I put a breakpoint in there, it never gets hit. When there are no arguments in the function though, it will get hit. I've tried replacing "String[]" with "object" and it still doesn't get hit, which I find odd. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to decorate your web service with the `[ScriptService]` attribute in order to allow client scripts to invoke it. Also if you are sending a JSON request you need to specify the content type. Another remark is about sending the request as an actual JSON object which could be achieved using the `JSON.stringify` method (maybe the `$('.sortable').sortable('serialize')` call already does this, I am not familiar, you just need to ensure that the POSTed value looks like this: `[ 'row1', 'row2', ... ]`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'MyWebService.asmx/SortTable',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify([ 'row1', 'row2', 'row3' ]),
    error: function () {
        alert('theres an error with AJAX');
    }
});
```

Comment: It has the [ScriptService] attribute, and will get called if there's no arguments in the function which is what really confuses me. I tried adding the content type but that seemed to throw off the JSON post. The serialize method is from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize). My JSON post looks like row[]=0&row[]=3&row[]=1&row[]=2 and so the parameters according to firebug are looking like: 
row[] 0
row[] 3
row[] 1
row[] 2